# Why error switching branches after squashing? Nothing to commit

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-squash

I just squashed my remote commits, then forced-pushed them to the remote. A `git status` shows no changes. Why then would I get this error when trying to checkout the develop branch?

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by checkout:
>           [file here]
>   Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
>   Aborting

Here is what was done:

```
git rebase -i origin/feature/EX-1576~14 feature/EX-1576
git push --force origin feature/EX-1576
```

And `git status` shows nothing:

```
$ git status
On branch feature/EX-1576
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/EX-1576'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

It's my understanding that the error occurs when you have local changes, but I don't have local changes. I simply want to do this:

```
git checkout develop
```

Comment: Are you on Linux, macOS or Windows?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Is `core.autocrlf` set? i.e. What does `git config --get core.autocrlf` say?

Comment: It returns true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Follow Git's advice: for each file that it names, move that file somewhere else (out of the way, perhaps out of the project entirely), or commit it.  Then do the checkout, and see what file(s) you got that replaced those files, and decide whether to keep the replacements, or to use the saved copies you made before the checkout.

Be careful with `git update-index --assume-unchanged` or `git update-index --skip-worktree`: these work well for some cases, but set you up for this particular trap.

Since you are on Windows, which defaults to conflating files named (e.g.) `readme` with other different files named `README`—Windows can't store both; it just clobbers one of them—be careful with case-sensitive file names, usually made by some Linux programmer. :-)

#### Long

> It's my understanding that the error occurs when you have local changes ...

That's not really right.  You get that error when the operation—in this case, `git checkout`—would overwrite some *state*.

Git isn't about *changes* at all.  Git is mostly about *commits*, and commits save *state*—a snapshot of all of your files, along with your metadata: your name and email address, the time you made the commit, and your log message as to why you made the commit, for instance.  (Included in this metadata is another critical item, the parent commit hash ID, but we can ignore that for this particular problem.)

The difference between state and changes is like talking about the weather: saying it's warmer today than yesterday tells you one thing, but not everything, about the temperature.  Saying that it was 15˚C (59˚F) yesterday, and is 20 / 68 today, tells you *everything* about the temperature.  (Well, about this one temperature, anyway.)  Note that it took two *states* to come up with the *change:* we have to subtract yesterday's temperature from today's to see how much warmer or colder it might be.

Anyway, commits store state: a full, complete copy of every file that was committed, as of the time it was committed.  This copy actually comes out of Git's *index*, but we get to ignore that fine distinction for the moment.  It's about to crop up in a moment, though.  So each commit is very much independent of every other commit.

Your *work-tree*, on the other hand, is not something Git saves (at all, really, because of the index).  You use it to work on your files, because the committed copies are in a special, frozen, compressed (sometimes very compressed), Git-only format.  To make these useful, Git needs to expand them out into ordinary-format files, that you can use and *change* if you like.  Those expanded copies go in your work-tree.

Now, a thing about the work-tree is that it's allowed to contain files that you won't commit.  These are what Git calls *untracked* files.  Normally, if there is a file in your work-tree that's is untracked—that won't be committed—Git will *complain* about that file.  You can make Git shut up about it by listing the untracked file in `.gitignore`, but this is trickier than it looks.  This is where Git smacks you in the face with the existence of the index, again.

The index is a weird and wonderful, but also obnoxious, thing that is pretty much unique to Git.  In between the commits, which store files in a frozen Git-only compressed form, and the work-tree, which lets you work on your files, Git puts a *third* copy of every file.  The index copy of each file is in the special Git-only format, but instead of being frozen, it's merely *ready* to freeze: kind of slushy, if you will.  The point is that you can *change* this copy, and that's what `git add` does: it copies a file from the work-tree, into the index.

It's actually the presence of the index copy that determines whether or not a file is tracked.  If the file is in the index, it's tracked; if not, it's untracked.  Listing a file in `.gitignore` means: *if it's not in the index, and is in the work-tree, don't complain.*  But it has a second side effect, which is: it gives Git permission to *destroy* the file, in some cases.

#### Filename case issues

Linux programmers happily write and commit two different files, one named `README` and other named `readme` or `Readme`.  Or they do the same with header files: `ip.h` and `IP.h` (in older Linux kernel trees).  When someone using a Mac or a Windows box tries to work with these commits, they get bitten by the fact that the *work-tree* on these systems can't put both files into place.  (Git's index handles it just fine, because the index is actually a file, `.git/index`.)

If you are switching from a commit that has a file named `README` to one that has `Readme`, or that has both, Git will sometimes get a little discombobulated by this, and not know what to do.  (Git needs to be smarter about this, someday.)

#### assume-unchanged and skip-worktree

In any case, suppose a file *is* in the index.  If you change the work-tree copy, Git will tell you that you have a modified tracked file.  If you don't want Git to keep reminding you about this, you can use `git update-index --assume-unchanged` or `git update-index --skip-worktree` to mark that file specially.

When you do this—and I think you probably did—Git *stops comparing the index copy of the file to the work-tree copy*, for `git status` commands, and does not copy the work-tree copy of the file over top of the index copy, for `git add` commands.  This means that you can take a configuration file, modify it for some reason, and yet have *new* commits—which use the *index* copy of the file—store the *original* version of the file, the one that came out of the commit and went into your work-tree before you set the assume-unchanged or skip-worktree bit.

But `git checkout` must, when it goes to switch to some other commit, *replace* the index copy of that file with the (different) committed copy in the commit you're going to switch to.  When this happens, Git will not only update the index copy, it will also overwrite the work-tree copy.  So if you have a file marked with either of these two bits, you can get that error when you use `git checkout`.

Is this a problem?  Maybe so, maybe not.  If you force `git checkout` to check out that other commit, Git will overwrite the index entry with the file from the other commit, and replace the work-tree copy of that file with the one from the other commit.  It's up to you to decide whether this is OK, and if not, whether you need to move the file out of the way first, or clear those bits and go ahead and add-and-commit the file.

#### There are also corner cases with half-ignored files

Suppose, on the other hand, you *didn't* set those index bits with `git update-index`.  You could still have an ordinary, untracked file, perhaps even one listed in a `.gitignore` to keep Git quiet about it.  But some *other* commit might have (a different version of) that same file, and if you have Git switch to *that* commit, Git will have to *replace* your untracked work-tree file with the version out of the commit where it's a *tracked* file.

In this case, `git checkout` will sometimes—but not always—also complain.  Usually it will say that the checkout would overwrite an *untracked* file.  If the file is listed in `.gitignore`, this will give some parts of Git permission to clobber it.   Fortunately `git checkout` is usually pretty careful about these things.

Comment: In my case, there is one file that Git is complaining about. So you're suggesting to copy that file somewhere else, then do a force checkout of develop? Then, if something is wrong with that file, I can reference the backup I made? BTW, that file isn't something I set in `.gitignore` or the `--skip-worktree` thing.

Comment: I ask about making a backup copy, because `git status` shows there is nothing to commit, so I don't have that option.

Comment: Yes, if you save the file (or move it out of the way entirely) the checkout can proceed (without `-f` if you move it out of the way). Then you can see what's different and decide what to do. If it's not an assume-unchanged/skip-worktree thing (and I had the idea it was not ignored already), that's pretty much the only option.

Comment: That file is tracked. If I move it out of the way, won't that cause a local change?

Comment: Moving it will leave a hole in the shape of that file name, in the work-tree, after which Git won't mind filling the hole. :-)

Comment: Oh, wow. That looks exactly like what just happened. I moved the file to a folder outside the repo, just as a backup. Then I checked out develop and it worked like it should. And the file is back where it should be. WTF? Things look good now. So did Git just get something messed up? And checking out develop cleared it?

Comment: No, what's going on is that the file in the commit you checked out *is* different. Exactly what the difference is, is not clear—there are some encoding tricks (end of line stuff for instance) that makes for puzzlements. I avoid Windows myself and don't normally run into any of these problems, though a few of them show up on MacOS too.

Comment: That's where my confusion lies. If the file is different, why wouldn't it show up when running `git status`?

Comment: That's not entirely clear; I'd need to examine the actual system.